# fill_gaps doesn't add new values

Tags: r

I'm trying to fill out gaps in my dataframe with the fill_gaps function. I would like to add the mean of the column and use group_by_key().
`rain_full` is a tsibble.

```r
rain_full <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(14975, 14976, 14977, 14978,14979, 14980, 14981, 17164, 17165, 17166), class = "Date"), Location = structure(c(3L,3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 48L, 48L, 48L), .Label = c("Adelaide","Albany", "Albury", "AliceSprings", "BadgerysCreek", "Ballarat","Bendigo", "Brisbane", "Cairns", "Canberra", "Cobar", "CoffsHarbour","Dartmoor", "Darwin", "GoldCoast", "Hobart", "Katherine", "Launceston","Melbourne", "MelbourneAirport", "Mildura", "Moree", "MountGambier","MountGinini", "Newcastle", "Nhil", "NorahHead", "NorfolkIsland","Nuriootpa", "PearceRAAF", "Penrith", "Perth", "PerthAirport","Portland", "Richmond", "Sale", "SalmonGums", "Sydney", "SydneyAirport","Townsville", "Tuggeranong", "Uluru", "WaggaWagga", "Walpole","Watsonia", "Williamtown", "Witchcliffe", "Wollongong", "Woomera"), class = "factor"), MinTemp = c(23.2, 20.1, 13.6, 13.9, 16,16.5, 16.1, 19.2, 20.2, 19.6)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), key = structure(list(Location = structure(c(3L, 48L), .Label = c("Adelaide", "Albany","Albury", "AliceSprings", "BadgerysCreek", "Ballarat", "Bendigo","Brisbane", "Cairns", "Canberra", "Cobar", "CoffsHarbour","Dartmoor", "Darwin", "GoldCoast", "Hobart", "Katherine","Launceston", "Melbourne", "MelbourneAirport", "Mildura","Moree", "MountGambier", "MountGinini", "Newcastle", "Nhil","NorahHead", "NorfolkIsland", "Nuriootpa", "PearceRAAF","Penrith", "Perth", "PerthAirport", "Portland", "Richmond","Sale", "SalmonGums", "Sydney", "SydneyAirport", "Townsville","Tuggeranong", "Uluru", "WaggaWagga", "Walpole", "Watsonia","Williamtown", "Witchcliffe", "Wollongong", "Woomera"), class = "factor"),.rows = structure(list(1:7, 8:10), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of","vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), index = structure("Date", ordered = TRUE), index2 = "Date", interval = structure(list(year = 0, quarter = 0, month = 0, week = 0, day = 1, hour = 0,minute = 0, second = 0, millisecond = 0, microsecond = 0,nanosecond = 0, unit = 0), .regular = TRUE, class = c("interval","vctrs_rcrd", "vctrs_vctr")), groups = structure(list(Location = structure(c(3L,48L), .Label = c("Adelaide", "Albany", "Albury", "AliceSprings","BadgerysCreek", "Ballarat", "Bendigo", "Brisbane", "Cairns","Canberra", "Cobar", "CoffsHarbour", "Dartmoor", "Darwin", "GoldCoast","Hobart", "Katherine", "Launceston", "Melbourne", "MelbourneAirport","Mildura", "Moree", "MountGambier", "MountGinini", "Newcastle","Nhil", "NorahHead", "NorfolkIsland", "Nuriootpa", "PearceRAAF","Penrith", "Perth", "PerthAirport", "Portland", "Richmond", "Sale","SalmonGums", "Sydney", "SydneyAirport", "Townsville", "Tuggeranong","Uluru", "WaggaWagga", "Walpole", "Watsonia", "Williamtown","Witchcliffe", "Wollongong", "Woomera"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(1:7, 8:10), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of","vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_ts","grouped_df", "tbl_ts", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

When I run

```r
rain_done <- rain_full %>% 
  group_by_key() %>% 
  fill_gaps(MinTemp = mean(MinTemp, na.rm=TRUE), .full = TRUE)
```

the code runs, and gives no error. However nothing is added to the rain_done. Still NA's.

Any suggestions to what could be done?

Comment: Your code works perfectly on my machine, rain_done has 4384 obs of 3 variables and everything is filled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your provided data does not have any NAs, so I have added one at random in the `MinTemp` column.

```r
rain_full <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(14975, 14976, 14977, 14978,14979, 14980, 14981, 17164, 17165, 17166), class = "Date"), Location = structure(c(3L,3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 48L, 48L, 48L), .Label = c("Adelaide","Albany", "Albury", "AliceSprings", "BadgerysCreek", "Ballarat","Bendigo", "Brisbane", "Cairns", "Canberra", "Cobar", "CoffsHarbour","Dartmoor", "Darwin", "GoldCoast", "Hobart", "Katherine", "Launceston","Melbourne", "MelbourneAirport", "Mildura", "Moree", "MountGambier","MountGinini", "Newcastle", "Nhil", "NorahHead", "NorfolkIsland","Nuriootpa", "PearceRAAF", "Penrith", "Perth", "PerthAirport","Portland", "Richmond", "Sale", "SalmonGums", "Sydney", "SydneyAirport","Townsville", "Tuggeranong", "Uluru", "WaggaWagga", "Walpole","Watsonia", "Williamtown", "Witchcliffe", "Wollongong", "Woomera"), class = "factor"), MinTemp = c(23.2, 20.1, NA, 13.9, 16,16.5, 16.1, 19.2, 20.2, 19.6)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), key = structure(list(Location = structure(c(3L, 48L), .Label = c("Adelaide", "Albany","Albury", "AliceSprings", "BadgerysCreek", "Ballarat", "Bendigo","Brisbane", "Cairns", "Canberra", "Cobar", "CoffsHarbour","Dartmoor", "Darwin", "GoldCoast", "Hobart", "Katherine","Launceston", "Melbourne", "MelbourneAirport", "Mildura","Moree", "MountGambier", "MountGinini", "Newcastle", "Nhil","NorahHead", "NorfolkIsland", "Nuriootpa", "PearceRAAF","Penrith", "Perth", "PerthAirport", "Portland", "Richmond","Sale", "SalmonGums", "Sydney", "SydneyAirport", "Townsville","Tuggeranong", "Uluru", "WaggaWagga", "Walpole", "Watsonia","Williamtown", "Witchcliffe", "Wollongong", "Woomera"), class = "factor"),.rows = structure(list(1:7, 8:10), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of","vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), index = structure("Date", ordered = TRUE), index2 = "Date", interval = structure(list(year = 0, quarter = 0, month = 0, week = 0, day = 1, hour = 0,minute = 0, second = 0, millisecond = 0, microsecond = 0,nanosecond = 0, unit = 0), .regular = TRUE, class = c("interval","vctrs_rcrd", "vctrs_vctr")), groups = structure(list(Location = structure(c(3L,48L), .Label = c("Adelaide", "Albany", "Albury", "AliceSprings","BadgerysCreek", "Ballarat", "Bendigo", "Brisbane", "Cairns","Canberra", "Cobar", "CoffsHarbour", "Dartmoor", "Darwin", "GoldCoast","Hobart", "Katherine", "Launceston", "Melbourne", "MelbourneAirport","Mildura", "Moree", "MountGambier", "MountGinini", "Newcastle","Nhil", "NorahHead", "NorfolkIsland", "Nuriootpa", "PearceRAAF","Penrith", "Perth", "PerthAirport", "Portland", "Richmond", "Sale","SalmonGums", "Sydney", "SydneyAirport", "Townsville", "Tuggeranong","Uluru", "WaggaWagga", "Walpole", "Watsonia", "Williamtown","Witchcliffe", "Wollongong", "Woomera"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(1:7, 8:10), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of","vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_ts","grouped_df", "tbl_ts", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Remember to state the packages that you used - in this case I assume `library(tsibble)`

`fill_gaps` only makes implicit missing values explicit, as such it does not the change values of NAs. To accomplish this, you can use e.g. `tidyr::replace_na`.

Here's an example that does what you're after:

```r
rain_full %>% 
  as_tsibble(index=Date, key=Location) %>% 
  group_by_key() %>% 
  mutate(MinTemp = tidyr::replace_na(MinTemp, mean(MinTemp, na.rm=T)))
```

Since you already have NA values you actually don't need to use `fill_gaps()`. However, if there are missing date values in your full dataset, you should add it before `mutate()`.

See more in the documentation for `fill_gaps` [here](https://tsibble.tidyverts.org/reference/fill_gaps.html) and `replace_na` [here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/replace_na.html).